# Why is a Keras custom metric not called after each epoch? [SOLVED]

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using tensorflow 2.1 and tf.keras, and whether adding a custom Metric as a simple function or Metric subclassed instance, during training the custom metric appears only be called at the start of training and not after each epoch as I was expecting. The start of a run is below for example (much larger validation segment than usual as a test), where the metric is printing during `update_state()` and `result()` but only until epoch 1. In this case the metric is returning a dummy number that increments on each update call, reaching 2 and no further. Supplied metrics such as BinaryAccuracy *do* produce varying numbers after each epoch so I assume I'm missing or misunderstanding something. What could be the explanation for the observed behaviour?

```
update
result
Train on 4418 samples, validate on 4418 samples
Epoch 1/120
update
result
result
3800/4418 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1597 - binary_true_positives: 2.0000 result
4418/4418 [==============================] - 3s 622us/sample - loss: 0.1500 - binary_true_positives: 2.0000 - val_loss: 0.0986 - val_binary_true_positives: 2.0000
Epoch 2/120
4418/4418 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 0.0868 - binary_true_positives: 2.0000 - val_loss: 0.0643 - val_binary_true_positives: 2.0000
```

**SOLVED**: After looking further, custom metrics *are* being produced after each epoch as expected, it's just that the Python code to produce them isn't being executed. It dawned on me that the code was likely transformed to a TensorFlow graph (it is viewable in TensorBoard), and the metrics were generated via executing the compiled graph rather than the original Python code that led to the graph representation being produced.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? It would be much easier if we get an example we can run ourselves (can be with dummy 1 layer model, dummy data).

Comment: Thanks The code is part of a larger system and not self contained so I'll look at a minimal test case and update following that.

Comment: @ibarrond Thanks again. Figured out that TensorFlow graph execution would be the explanation.

Comment: you can still answer your own question and get points for it, it could help other people! At least explain briefly how you managed to solve it

Comment: if you want to print something every time the metric "graph" is evaluated, you can add `tf.print()` instead of `print()` since tf.print() is an operation within the model/fit graph

Answer (score 0):

Because things not change after each epoch. Training samples and validating are same and don't change over iteration.

Comment: Thanks. Validation data is necessarily the same, but the predictions made by the model will change after each epoch as the model evolves. As Metrics are used to evaluate model performance, which will vary from one epoch to the next, don't the metrics need to be applied to a fresh set of predictions on the validation data at the end of each training epoch?

Comment: number of samples are same. Prediction is performed in last at test. training and validation is performed in each epoch.

Comment: I believe I figured out the issue and have updated the question accordingly.